"quantity_and_stock_status" attribute is not functioning as expected on the product list page in Magento 2.4.6-p3, Enabled usage in product listing
I recently encountered an issue with the Magento default "quantity_and_stock_status" attribute. While this attribute is functioning properly on the product view page, it's not working on the product listing page even after enabling the "used_in_product_listing" setting in the backend.
On the product view page, it returns the proper result.
Array(
  ['is_in_stock'] => 1
  ['qty] => 1000
)

But in the product list it's returning null.


Which things you have try on category page?

First, I have set attribute intended to be used on the product list page, but the values are not appearing with the product list object. I have also attempted the following steps.
$_product->getQty()
$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty()
$_product->getQuantityAndStockStatus()['qty']
$_product->getStockItem()->getQty()
$_product->getStockData()->getQty()
Nothing seems to be working with this issue @Dhiren Vasoya
